# Is there any way I can keep two APIs live so I can send messages back and forth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I am doing a project where I have to keep two backend APIs live so I can send data back and forth.
Basically, the idea is, I will have two spring boot applications running on different ports. Now, I want to send JSON/XML data back and forth between them. I have looked into WebSockets but it seems they are only for client to server. I was wondering if there is any way I can achieve this

Comment: Websocket is not only for client to server. Server can also push data to the client.

Comment: What do you mean by "send data back and forth" - is this continuous communication like streaming data, or more like remote procedure calls?

Comment: hi Joe, yes I was thinking like there would be two hospitals running two different applications. Then, hospital 2 would try to request access for resources from hospital 1. in which case, hospital 1 would ask for attributes from the requester of hospital 2, it will directly ask the backend of hospital 2 (this would happen in the backend as I don't want the requester to see anything). then hospital 2 would send back the attributes to hospital 1. this is where I needed the live connection. However, I don't think I will use sockets anymore. I will just hit different APIs

Answer (score 0):

First, You could use Restful API so that could send data back and forth in one microservice and one port.

Second, Spring Boot has @Controller annotation to deal with Restful API.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping ( "/api_1" )
    public ModelAndView showView() {
        // API One logic
    }

    @RequestMapping ( "/api_2" )
    public ModelAndView showView() {
        // API Two logic
    }
```

Third, just call or post to "localhost://api_1" or "localhost://api_2", the APIs can run as you want.